# Why don't I have an output for the sorted merged list and sum(res[i]). I thought the sum function returned the sum of the newly merged array.

Tags: python, arrays

I should be printing two values based off my code the newly sorted array and the sum of the newly sorted array. But I keep on getting an error. Why don't I have an output for the sorted merged list and sum(res[i]). I thought the sum function returned the sum of the newly merged array. What does Python mean when it says the int object is not iterable. Can you please explain why the code isn't functioning properly. I apologize for the basic question as I am new to python.

## Python program to merge two unsorted lists

```
# in sorted order

# Function to merge array in sorted order
def sortedMerge(a, b, res, n, m):
    # Sorting a[] and b[]
    a.sort()
    b.sort()


    # Merge two sorted arrays into res[]
    i, j, k = 0, 0, 0
    while (i < n and j < m):
        if (a[i] <= b[j]):
            res[k] = a[i]
            i += 1
            k += 1
        else:
            res[k] = b[j]
            j += 1
            k += 1

    while (i < n): # Merging remaining
                    # elements of a[] (if any)
        res[k] = a[i]
        i += 1
        k += 1

    while (j < m): # Merging remaining
                    # elements of b[] (if any)
        res[k] = b[j]
        j += 1
        k += 1

# Driver code
a = [ 5, 5, 5, 5 ]
b = [ 100, 100, 100, 100, 100 ]
n = len(a)
m = len(b)

# Final merge list
res = [0 for i in range(n + m)]
sortedMerge(a, b, res, n, m)
print ("Sorted merged list :")
for i in range(n + m):
    print (res[i])
print(sum(res[i]))
```

Comment: You need `print(sum(res))`; at that stage of your script `res[i]` is just the last item in `res`.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply achieve this by executing the following code:

```
def sortandmerge(a,b):
    #Returns the sum of the lists
    return sum(list(set(a+b)))
```

If you specifically want the function to return the sorted list too, then

```
def sortandmerge(a,b):
    #Returns the sum of the lists
    res = list(set(a+b))
    return sum(res), res
```

And then use the .sort() function where you're receiving the res

Comment: Im normally would be able to solve it but Im in a hackathon and I'm so tired I can barely see. Thank you for your answer